# Change run action in Visual Studio database project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I have a database project in Visual Studio 2008, and I want the ability to run a preprocessor on my sql code (using it to allow for variable database names without resorting to dynamic sql).  So I'd like to change what action occurs when I hit the run button to include running the code through the preprocessor automatically.

Is there a way to do this?  I looked through the dbp file, and there don't seem to be any options even close to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use **[SQLCMD Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833281.aspx)** in your database project scripts.

 (VS Menu: Data -> TSQL Editor -> SQLCMD Mode).

In your scripts you can define variables that get replaced when you run them. Example:

```
:SETVAR tablevar Customers
GO
SELECT * FROM $(tablevar) /* translates to SELECT * FROM Customers */
```